# Java: regex replace string

Tags: java, regex, replace

Consider the following String:

```
s = "Ralph was walking down the street, he saw Mary and fell in love with her. Judy loves her hair."
```

I've got an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> anaphora` with the correct matches and sentence number and `ArrayList<String> sentences` with the sentences from `s`. Both look like this:

```
anaphora.get(0) = [0, Ralph, he]
anaphora.get(1) = [0, Mary, her]
anaphora.get(2) = [0, the street]
anaphora.get(3) = [1, Judy, her]
anaphora.get(4) = [1, her hair]

sentences.get(0) = Ralph was walking down the street, he saw Mary and fell in love with her.
sentences.get(1) = Judy loves her hair.
```

Now the problem arises when trying to replace the substrings.

```
sentence = sentences.get(0);
if (anaphora.get(0).size()>2){
    example1 = sentence.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]"+anaphora.get(0).get(i)+"[^a-zA-Z]", anaphora.get(0).get(1));
    example2 = sentence.replaceAll(anaphora.get(0).get(i), anaphora.get(0).get(1));
}
```

Output will be:

```
example1 = Ralph was walking down the street,Ralphsaw Mary and fell in love with her.
example2 = Ralph was walking down tRalph street, Ralph saw Mary and fell in love with Ralphr.
```

The expected output would be in such a way that 'he' gets replaced with 'Ralph':

```
Ralph was walking down the street, Ralph saw Mary and fell in love with her.
```

**Question** How can I fix my regex replace so that ONLY the correct 'he' gets replaced?

Comment: what are trying to do? Can you provide a CLEAR example?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: try with boundary `\b` pattern. Your pattern will be `\\bhe\\b` for matching exactly `he`. for more see :http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: `sentence.replaceAll(anaphora.get(0).get(i), anaphora.get(1))` replacement is `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: I fixed my question, hopefully it's a bit more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above, you can use a word boundary, for example:

```
String s = "Ralph was walking down the street, he saw Mary and fell in love with her.";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\bhe\\b", "Ralph"));
```

prints:

> Ralph was walking down the street, Ralph saw Mary and fell in love with her.

Answer (score 0):

you need to be careful of the blanks. so your regex should only do the replacement, if the replaced string is a word.